# Parallel Space alternative with apk installation support

Tags: applications

So, there exist some apps which can work as a container to install (Clone to be precise) other apps in it. One eg app is [Parallel Space](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl&hl=en&gl=US)

It's not hard to find a whole bunch of them, but all of them lack the ability to install them directly from apk file. It requires the app to be installed on the main device first to be cloned (after that you can uninstall them from the main device of course), some of them do allow direct installation from Google Play but that's all about it while I'm looking for a solution that can install from apk files too.

I'm **not** looking for multiple-user solutions (that Island-like apps provide).

I'm aware of VMOS-like apps, which **do** support installing apk (by emulating a whole Android environment, which seems overhead (i.e. an expensive option) for me).

Some conceptions that I hold: (please correct them if I'm wrong)

- Apps inside [Parallel Space]-like apps **can't** run in the background if the host app itself is not running in the background.
- VMOS-like apps are very resource-consuming (CPU, GPU, RAM, Storage) than [Parallel Space]-like apps.

Comment: If you want to install an app inside a container you need some sort of virtualized Android environment. What an app can do is very limited on an unrooted device, therefore I would be surprised if an app like you are searching for would exist.

Comment: @Robert Yup, I have a rooted device. Do you have any suggestions now? (Alto, I don't think root is needed for this (Check VMOS), that's why I didn't add it in the OP).

Comment: Yes root is not necessary if you emulate everything. But you are searching for a way between ParallelSpace and VMOS. And even if this sounds reasonable this does not means anybody have ever tried it or built an app to do so. At least I don't know what you are looking for. In my opinion you should modify your question and describe why you dislike the ParallelSpace approach. May be someone has an idea how to circumvent your problem with ParallelSpace

Comment: It's already very clear in the Title, that I don't want to install the app on phone before using it on parallel space. (You can do that if the app is in Playstore, but I want to install from APK). All of these is already explained in details on the OP from the very beginning. BTW, I'd appreciate your root option, if you have any.